# How to loop through all opened workbooks in the Excel Javascript API?

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm trying to switch from VBA to new Excel Javascript API, but I cannot find analogue to VBA collections and methods to loop through all opened workbooks.

Usually in VBA I was able just write something like this:

```
for each i in workbooks
next i
```

using [workbooks object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks)
or just call opened workbook by name or index
[`workbook(index/name of workbook`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook)

So, in JS office I found only something similar to VBA function 'workbook.open' JS -`document.getElementById("file");` in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks) and [this article has no mentions at all](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbook?view=office-js#properties)

I've tried to find something about 'Office.context.document' in Google and in [in official repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/develop/support-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins.md), but all links have 404 error.

Does anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is no Office JS API right now that can get a reference to an opened Excel workbook other than the one the add-in is running in. But it is a good idea. Please vote up this suggestion at the [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/33923122-excel-js-should-support-already-open-excel-workboo).